# Mac Application Menu always english

Tags: macos, qt, localization

I have to port a Windows program with Qt UI to Mac OSX. The problem is that the application menu is always in english. I tried such things like http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/21134 or setting the “Localization native development region” in my Info.plist to German, but nothing works.
The translation of the other labels is implemented with qm files.
In my /Contents/Resources/ directory are only 2 files: the empty qt.conf and my icon file.
Putting a German.lproj dorectory with a localisation.plist or locversin.plist doesn’t work.

The program supports only english and german. Is there a way to translate the application menu in regard to the system language?

I use Mac OSX 10.8.5 with XCode 4.6.2
Qt version is 4.8.4

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.  My app translates to Spanish on 10.9, Qt5.3, Xcode 5.  But the same executable doesn't translate on 10.7.5 or 10.8.2.  I too tried some of the things you tried.

Note that for german, I think you need qtbase_de.qm.  The qt_de.qm files just imports others.  I think the context MAC_APPLICATION_MENU is translated in qtbase_de.ts (which you can read, its XML.)

I found that on 10.7.5, in a terminal, the environment variable LANG is always en_EN.utf-8, even though the machine was booted with another language.  I don't think I changed my environment.  I think that is the environment variable that Qt reads to determine the locale.  I'm wondering if its not something else I need to do on older OSX, other than just choose a new language in System Preferences.